# Playfair Cipher in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: algorithm, flutter, networking, encryption, dart

Is there any library for the implementation of playfair cipher in dart? Just new flutter dev and have no idea about how the 2d matrix and other functionalities would be perform in dart.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for [**Java**](https://github.com/mckennapsean/code-examples/blob/master/Java/Playfair.java) and by following the code, the only two libraries being used are:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**Point Class** is available in **Dart**: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-math/Point-class.html

Also for **Scanner**:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-string_scanner_string_scanner/StringScanner-class.html
- https://pub.dev/packages/string_scanner

For 2D Vector List you'd need to use something like:

```
List<List<String>> // or any other object
```

Other than that, I'm not seeing any limitations on Dart to make it happen.

If you're looking for already good implemented encryption libraries, you have:

- [**PointyCastle**](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle)
- [**SQLCipher**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sqlcipher)